# What does this line of abap code do assign component

Tags: abap

what does this below mentioned code in abap mean :

```
ASSIGN COMPONENT iv_time_col OF STRUCTURE <ls_req> TO <seq_time>.
```

Comment: Questions like that can usually be answered by just marking the keyword (in this case `ASSIGN COMPONENT`) and pressing F1 to load the ABAP documentation. This works both in  the ABAP development workbench in SAPGui and in Eclipse with ADT.

Answer (score 3):

It is dynamically getting field (field name in the iv_time_col variable) value from <ls_req> structure to  <seq_time>.